# Rails 4: PayPal IPN, Payments for various Sellers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on a Rails Application where Users can buy Items other Users shared previously.
The payments should be flexible to allow the User who shared an Item to get the money a buyer pais.
1) Is it possible to create Flexible Paypal Payments (Different Seller, different Price for each Item)?

2) Can you use the PayPal IPN with Donations to check whether a buyer paid or not?

3) If not, what is the most efficient way to achive that goal?

Thanks in advance for each answer! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I'd approach this:

- Is it possible to create Flexible Paypal Payments?
  Different sellers: Do you want them to be able to receive the payment directly in their Paypal? If that's the case, you'd need to provide them the details to create a Paypal merchant account and securely store those details, but I don't think that's the approach you want to take;
  Most payment solutions provider gives a way to send payment to multiple vendors/merchants, which you may instead want to set up or even in your application, you can set up a kind of payment stuff to ensure that integrates with Paypal's API to pay your vendor soon as you receive payments for items. 
  So, yes it's possible, the different sellers could be tricky, but all other things are possible!
- Can you use the PayPal IPN with Donations to check whether a buyer paid or not?
  Absolutely, that's one of the biggest benefit of the IPN is that your application gets to know on time if someone has made a payment. You only have to validate this record with Paypal and, not like it's often necessary compare the payment amount